# Packery.js and <select> - how to make contols clickable?

Tags: draggable, packery

I use Packery.js with ability to drag element. Inside the container I have `<select>` tag.

When I click anywhere on the container, drag event starts. Also on child elements. This prevents drop down from opening. Example under this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tschareck/tXdqw/1/

How can I override dragging, and instead open dropdown, when I click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `handle`.
Answer to this question:

 
https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly/issues/37